# setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key house_type

Tags: ios

I met this problem but the app didn't crash. I have checked xib file and there is no connection wrong in IBOutLet. Could anyone tell me why?
Following are images of my code
[code in model.h file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSGKs.jpg)

[code in model.m file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV0XX.jpg)

Comment: looks like you are using wrong keypath for your model.

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F and then `house_type`. It searches in all files including the XIB files.

Comment: `[<TGRealcaseInfoModel 0x7fb6ebdb2240> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key house_type.`  Here is the full information. Dose this mean the mistake is in TGRealcaseInfoModel?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value passed on house_type key. It may be Integer or something, which is not supported by NSDictionary. The key value must be object type.

Comment: the value passed on house_type key is NSString type, `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *houseType;` and I set houseType property as NSString type

Answer (score 0):

Check your xib files, there is wrong outlet connection with `house_type`. Remove the older connection from xib.

Comment: Finally I find the solution, because TGRealcaseInfoModel's superclass 'TGSeeCaseModel' follow protocle `@interface TGSeeCaseModel : NSObject<TGBottomBarModel, TGCollctionList>`. TGBottomBarModel has property 'house_type' and I didn't write it in TGRealcaseInfoModel.h file